# How to increase the size of window buttons on Ubuntu?

Tags: titlebar, window-buttons

I have found settings to only increase the launcher size. Could anyone help me in increasing the size of window-buttons (minimize, maximize and close buttons) on Ubuntu (if possible titlebar size too)?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 17.10 which defaults to Gnome now. Can someone update the answer to this question.  I can't seem to find a way to change the window-buttons size.

Comment: Apparent duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/1155216/how-to-resize-window-icons-min-max-close-ubuntu-18-04-gnome -- which has one additional solution in terms of the gtk-3.0 config file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to System Settings > Displays > Scale for menu and title bars

Comment: I tries your answer but there are only two options - 100% or 200%. Selecting the 200% option is far much more bigger than expected. Also this scaling increases the size of everything on the screen. It would be good if you could provide some other way to achieve increment of only title bar buttons.

Answer (score 0):

`Settings` -> `Universal Access` has a few options related to size of window elements.
Particularly, `Large Test` does increase the size of buttons in some supporting apps.

I'd suggest you give it a try to see if it fits your needs