# How to resize window icons (min, max, close), Ubuntu 18.04 Gnome

Tags: gnome, icons, window-buttons

I've tried all the tweaks I could find on the internet and I still can't resize the window icons (close, min, max). Everything else, I've been able to resize perfectly, but not even scale changes them, as I posted in the screen, the text becomes big, but those particular icons remain small and no font size whatsoever appears to have any effect.

[image: Icons too small]

Any way to change those icons size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To increase the size of **all** user interface elements, you need to change the scaling factor in "*Settings*" - "*Displays*". Unfortunately, that can only be set in integer values. Once this factor set, you can then use the "*Scaling factor*" to adjust the size of the fonts. Try the combination that works best.

Alternatively, you may try to reduce the resolution of your monitor in order to have all elements displayed larger.

These are all not optimal solutions.Currently, there is no better option in GNOME Shell. Work is underway to support fractional scaling, which would resolve the entire issue.

On the other hand, this may be subjective. On my HD screen (1920 x 1200), these icons are quite similar in size to the ones you show in your screenshot. So another option for you may be to live with it a little time to see if you get used to it.

Comment: Ah i see, i'm absolutely new to Ubuntu (or Linux actually). Is there another desktop you would recomend in your personal opinion, that scales well with HD res?. I do need to work on this resolution for ease in web development, so i feel lowering res is not a good option in my case.

Comment: Unity desktop, the desktop of the Ubuntu company that they unfortunately discontinued. It can still be installed and is now community maintained. Perhaps also KDE desktop, which uses completely different systemlibraries.

Comment: KDE sounds good, i'll give it a shot. Thanks again!

Comment: If you're trying "KDE", please first try it thoroughly in a VM or on a test machine. Removing "KDE" completely, in case you don't like it, isn't trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the following to `~/.config/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` helps a great deal for me, on a 90-micron pixel-pitch screen. Specifically it increases the size of too-small title bar icons, without seeming to disturb much of anything else:

```
headerbar image {
    -gtk-icon-transform: scale(2.5);
}
```

I suppose if the problem were that those icons were too large, you could do the same thing with a scale factor less than one.