# Increase size of window buttons

Tags: gnome, display-resolution, window, scaling

My Ubuntu 20.04 installation is attached to a TV as a display. The window buttons (minimize, maximize, and close) are WAY too small at the distance I'm sitting away from the display. How do I increase their size?

This is related to displaying Ubuntu on a 48-inch full HD TV.

Comment: See also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/778981/how-to-increase-the-size-of-window-buttons-on-ubuntu

Comment: Try **Settings/Screen Display/Scale** in Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to increase the size of window buttons on Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/778981/how-to-increase-the-size-of-window-buttons-on-ubuntu)

Comment: @vanadium No. That scales all elements.